# use babel-loader but Object.assign is not a function

Tags: webpack, babeljs

`{ test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader?optional[]=runtime'}`

I installed babel-runtime

I use webpack with babel-loader config above, but get Object.assign is not function. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to install babel-runtime.

```
npm install babel-runtime --save-dev
```

Then you can use the following as a loader in your webpack config -

```
{
  test: /\.js?$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loaders: ['babel?optional=runtime']
}
```

or

```
{
  test: /\.js?$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: 'babel-loader?optional=runtime'
}
```

Comment: If you exclude node_modules, does it transpile the code for libraries that use Object.assign?

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you just use `babel` as the loader:

```
{ test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel'}
```