# Webpack babel-loader isn't reading .babelrc

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

When I run babel by itself it reads the `.babelrc` and transpiles as expected. However, when I run webpack with `webpack` and `babel-loader` it doesn't work.

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": ["env"]
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: __dirname + '/src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/dist',
        path: __dirname + '/dist'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js?/,
                include: __dirname + 'src',
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        port: 8080,
        historyApiFallback: {
            index: 'index.html'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I remember right, it should be `targets` directly without that `browsers` bit within. You can also have the browser definition at `.browserslistrc` to achieve the same result.

Comment: Never mind. Just try `.browserslistrc`. It should pick it up.

Comment: Also keep in mind that your current browser definition won’t include a lot of old browsers. If you want to support IE 11, you should include it there.

Comment: @JuhoVepsäläinen webpack still isn't picking up the `.babelrc` even when I just use the `env` preset and no browserlist options

Comment: Where do you place webpack.config.js and .babelrc. And where do you run webpack?

Comment: @imcvampire all at the root of the project. Both babel and webpack compile without errors, it just seems like webpack and babel-loader aren't using the `.babelrc` preset. And it didn't fix things when I put the babel config inside the `webpack.config.js`.

Comment: The same issue. But I'm sure that Webpack reads .babelrc, because if I change .babelrc content to `{"presets": []}` (remove preset), it doesn't transpile the sources at all and UglifyJs fails on arrow functions. But the question remains: **how to include polyfils for old browsers?** e.g IE 8... bablerc syntax `"presets": [["env", {"targets": { "browsers": ["IE >= 8"] }}]]` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue and that's what I found out. Setting up the `debug` option in `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["last 2 versions", "IE >= 8"]
      },
      "debug": true
    }]
  ]
}
```

shows that browsering works:

> Using targets: {   "chrome": "61",   "android": "4.4.3",   "edge":
>   "15",   "firefox": "56",   "ie": "8",   "ios": "10.3",   "safari":
>   "10.1" }
>
> Modules transform: commonjs
>
> Using plugins:   check-es2015-constants {"android":"4.4.3","ie":"8"}
>   transform-es2015-arrow-functions {"android":"4.4.3","ie":"8"}
>   transform-es2015-block-scoped-functions {"android":"4.4.3","ie":"8"}
>   transform-es2015-block-scoping {"android":"4.4.3","ie":"8"}
>   transform-es2015-classes {"android":"4.4.3","ie":"8"}
>   transform-es2015-computed-properties {"android":"4.4.3","ie":"8"}
>   transform-es2015-destructuring
>   {"android":"4.4.3","edge":"15","ie":"8"}
>   transform-es2015-duplicate-keys {"android":"4.4.3","ie":"8"}
>   transform-es2015-for-of {"android":"4.4.3","ie":"8"}
>   transform-es2015-function-name
>   {"android":"4.4.3","edge":"15","ie":"8"}
>   ...

My webpack config looks just

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel-loader'
    }
}
```

But that does not solve all the problems. Investigating the transpiled distributive, I could not find some expected things like polyfill for `Array.prototype.reduce` that should be polyfilled for IE 8. But the idea is (as I can understand) that it is not the responsibility of the `babel-core` transpiler. And we need to use [babel-polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/) or [core-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js). So polyfilling in a webpack configuration is a separate task and setting up `browsers` option in `.babelrc` is just a part the story.

See also related topics on the [GitHub](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/73) and on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32148218/why-does-object-assign-require-a-polyfill-when-babel-loader-is-being-used).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to read the `.babelrc` in the **webpack.config.js**:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const babelrc = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '.babelrc'))
babelrc = JSON.parse(babelrc)


module.exports = {
    //...
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js?/,
                include: __dirname + 'src',
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: babelrc
            }
        ]
    }
    //...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As what I understand, you want your configuration file `.babelrc` (external file) shall read by webpack, based on their [babel configuration](https://babeljs.io/docs/options#configfile) there is an option `options.configFile` that you may use to locate your babel config

Answer (score -1):

Edited the `webpack.config.js` and removed the `.babelrc`.

https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: __dirname + '/src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/dist',
        path: __dirname + '/dist'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['env']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        port: 8080,
        historyApiFallback: {
            index: 'index.html'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in question, you define loaded inside `module.loaders [{...}]`  and in the answer, you are using  `module.rules[{...}]` , does both syntax do the same same thing!!

Comment: I guess `loaders` was v1 and `rules` is v2+. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002099/rules-vs-loaders-in-webpack-whats-the-difference

Answer (score -1):

The fact is that babel-loader will find .babelrc file in the transpiled files directorty, not your project directory。 So you should write the babelrc with .babelrc file's path in the webpack.config.js file