# Simple babel.js standalone test not working in Chrome v40 due to "undefined is not a function" un-polyfilled functions

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I'm new to babel, and just trying to play around with the simple browser-based babel.js standalone, but I'm running into some problems even with a very simple "hello world" type example. Here's some code that works fine in Chrome 70, but fails with "undefined is not a function" in Chrome 40:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.2.5/babel.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
async function test() {}  
console.log("done");
</script>
```

- [JSBin link](https://jsbin.com/furokatapu/edit?html,console) for testing this code
- [Browserling link](https://www.browserling.com/browse/win/7/chrome/40/https://jsbin.com/furokatapu/edit?html,console) for testing on Chrome 40

Here's the stack trace, screenshotted from the browserling page:

[image]

And here's the offending bit of code:

[image]

This seems to be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32148218/why-does-object-assign-require-a-polyfill-when-babel-loader-is-being-used/32148277), but I'd have thought that the standalone would "stand alone" and not require any extra stuff to polyfill it. At a file size of 5.7mb, shouldn't `Object.assign` be polyfilled? Maybe I'm missing something here?

Comment: Polyfill's and Babel are really too separate things, if your want to target version 40 of chrome then your going to need to load a polyfill.  There are lots of ways to implement polyfill's, manually of course.  But there is also this site you could use -> https://polyfill.io/v2/docs/

Comment: Ahhh, thank you! I just assumed that 5.7mb meant that all the polyfills were included, but I guess that would have made the file even larger still. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Keith's comment for letting me know that I need to include polyfills separately. Here's a working "hello world" with babel.js:

```
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.js?features=default,es5,es6&flags=gated,always"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.2.5/babel.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel" data-presets="es2015,es2016,es2017,stage-3">
async function test() { return 10; }  
console.log("done");
</script>
```

**Edit**: When testing it with my real code I was getting "runtimeGenerator not defined" messages, so this isn't a complete solution. I tried including it straight from the source, and it seemed to work, but then I was getting "undefined is not a function" again, and so to save my what is left of my hair and sanity I stepped away from the computer.

**Edit 2:** Here's what I ended up needing:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/facebook/regenerator/packages/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js"></script>
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.js?features=default,es5,es6,Array.prototype.@@iterator,Array.prototype.entries,Array.prototype.find,Array.prototype.findIndex,Array.prototype.copyWithin,Array.prototype.findIndex,Array.prototype.includes,Array.prototype.keys,Array.prototype.values,DOMTokenList.prototype.@@iterator,DocumentFragment,Element.prototype.dataset,EventSource,Function.name,HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toBlob,HTMLDocument,MutationObserver,NodeList.prototype.@@iterator,IntersectionObserver,IntersectionObserverEntry,NodeList.prototype.@@iterator,Object.entries,Object.values,Promise.prototype.finally,RegExp.prototype.flags,String.fromCodePoint,String.prototype.codePointAt,String.prototype.padEnd,String.prototype.padStart,String.prototype.repeat,Symbol.hasInstance,Symbol.isConcatSpreadable,Symbol.match,Symbol.replace,Symbol.search,Symbol.species,Symbol.split,Symbol.toPrimitive,Symbol.toStringTag,console.exception,fetch,screen.orientation,setImmediate&flags=gated,always"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.2.5/babel.js"></script>
<script>
  var beforeCode = "YOUR ES6+ CODE";
  var afterCode = Babel.transform(beforeCode, {
    presets: ['es2015','es2016','es2017','stage-3'],
    plugins: ['transform-async-to-generator','transform-regenerator'],
  }).code;
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.innerHTML = afterCode;
  document.head.appendChild(script);
</script>
```

I also needed to add a `NodeList.forEach` polyfill which polyfill.io doesn't support.